# Using streams to group Map attributes from inner objects?

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream, java-11

I'm learning Java 8 - Java 11 and I got a code that I'm converting to [java-streams](/questions/tagged/java-streams). I have the following classes:

```
class Resource {
   List<Capability> capabilities;
}

class Capability {
   String namespace;
   Map<String, Object> attributes;
}
```

I have a stream of Resources and I want to extract all its capabilities attributes from two different namespaces ("a", "b") to a `Map<Resource, Map<String, Object>>` that I have sure that do not have duplicates keys.

I did many attempts using map, flatMap but with those, I can't keep a reference of the main resource object. Using the new feature of java9 I could progress, but I'm stuck on the code below where I was able to return all attributes, but in a set. 
I was not able yet to filter by a capability namespace and also put them in a map:

```
Map<Resource, Set<Object>> result = pResolved.stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(t -> t, flatMapping(
            resource -> resource.getCapabilities(null).stream(),
            flatMapping(
                    cap -> cap.getAttributes().entrySet().stream(),
                    toSet()))));
```

Seems that I'm on the right path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could instead use `Collectors.toMap` as the `downstream` :

```
Map<Resource, Map<String, Object>> result = pResolved
        .stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(Function.identity(),
                flatMapping(resource -> resource.getCapabilities().stream(),
                        flatMapping(cap -> cap.getAttributes().entrySet().stream(),
                                toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue)))));
```

Comment: *Note*: This is assuming there wouldn't be duplicate keys across multiple `Map`s, or else you could also write a custom merge function for them inside the same downstream Collector.

Comment: Yep, this seem the way to go! 
I'm trying to figure out a way to filter by the Capability's namespace attribute without lost reference from resource object.

Answer (score 6):

There is a way using only [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) methods as well:

```
Map<String, Set<Object>> result = pResolved.stream()                        
    .map(Resource::getCapabilities)                         // Stream<List<Capability>>
    .flatMap(List::stream)                                  // Stream<Capability>
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(                              // Map<String, Set<Object>>
        c -> c.getNamespace(),                              // Key: String (namespace)
        i -> new HashSet<>(i.getAttributes().values())));   // Value: Set of Map values
```

Let's assume the sample input is:

```
Resource [capabilities=[
    Capability [namespace=a, attributes={a1=aa1, a2=aa2, a3=aa3}]]]
Resource [capabilities=[
    Capability [namespace=b, attributes={b2=bb2, b3=bb3, b1=bb1}], 
    Capability [namespace=c, attributes={c3=cc3, c1=cc1, c2=cc2}]]]
```

Then the code above would result in:

```
a: [aa1, aa3, aa2]
b: [bb1, bb3, bb2]
c: [cc1, cc3, cc2]
```

Comment: Hi Nicolas, but the problem using java-8 is that I lost reference from resource object when I do the first .map().
I need a Map<Resource, Map<String, Object>. 
Thanks for editing the question.